# Choose only one member of a list that is a cell of a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have many data frames inside a list, one of the data frames inside that list is the one below:

```
structure(list(`res.log[[i]]` = list("11", "8", c("7", "u"), 
    "11", "7", "4", "1", "6", "u", c("1", "7"), "1", "u", "u", 
    "u", c("20", "11", "18", "17"), "7", "10", "10", "2", "17", 
    c("1", "7"), "7", "14", "u", "7", c("4", "u"), c("1", "7"
    ), "7", "2", "10", "20", "8", "4", "7"), `as.factor(test.folds.trimmed[[i]]$tp)` = structure(c(3L, 
14L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 14L, 3L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 
2L, 14L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 
12L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("1", "10", "11", "14", "17", 
"18", "2", "20", "22", "4", "6", "7", "8", "u"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("res.log[[i]]", 
"as.factor(test.folds.trimmed[[i]]$tp)"), row.names = c(NA, -34L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The cells of the data frame itself are 'list' data types. As you can see in the first column, some of the cells have 2 or 3 values. **What I want to do for such cells in 1st column that have more than one value, is that I simply want to choose the value that is equal to to corresponding row in the 2nd column**. If none of them is equal to the value in the respective cell in the 2nd column then one is randomly taken, it does not matter which, it can always be the first one, this doesn't matter much, any of them can be taken.

For example, in the image below, you can see a part of the above data set. What I want to do is that for 3rd row in the 1st column, I will only keep "7" because it is equal to the value in the 3rd row 2nd column. And then in the 10th row and the 15th row it does not matter which one I choose, any of them can be chosen.

[Data objects screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrNOr.png)

The code I have written is this, but it works very strangely. It changes ALL of the values in the first column to the first value!!!

```
for(FOLDS in 1){
  for(rows in 1:nrow(res.log[[FOLDS]])){
    if( any(res.log[[FOLDS]][,1][[rows]] == 
res.log[[FOLDS]][,2][[rows]]) ) res.log[[FOLDS]][,1][[rows]] <-
            c(res.log[[FOLDS]][,1][[rows]][which(res.log[[FOLDS]][,1][[rows]] == 
res.log[[FOLDS]][,2][[rows]])])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, using a `for` loop, with your data in `dat`:

```
dat[,3] <- 0 #initialize a new column to check 

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
    if(length(unlist(dat[i,1])) > 1){
        if(any(unlist(dat[i,1]) == dat[i,2])){
           dat[i,3] <- as.character(dat[i,2])
        }else{
            dat[i,3] <- as.character(sample(unlist(dat[i,1]), 1))
        }
    }else{
        dat[i,3] <- as.character(dat[i,1])
    }
}

dat[c(3, 6:10),]
   res.log[[i]] as.factor(test.folds.trimmed[[i]]$tp) V3
3          7, u                                     7  7
6             4                                     4  4
7             1                                    22  1
8             6                                     6  6
9             u                                    20  u
10         1, 7                                     u  1
```

We first check if the list in the first column has `length > 1`. If its `length > 1`, we then check to see if `any` of the values in the list in the first column match the value of the second column. If there is a match, we store the value from the 2nd column. If there isn't a match, we `sample` one item from the list in the first column. If its `length == 1`, we just store the value in the first column. I'm not entirely sure how fast this solution will be, however.

Comment: Fantastic. Worked like a charm without a flaw. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
# renamed the columns to simplify the work!
colnames(df)= letters[1:2]
```

---

```
# another concised approach of 'for-loop'
df$c <- apply(df, 1, function(x) unlist(x$a)[match(x$b,unlist(x$a), nomatch = 1)])
```

---

```
# approach 2.    
func <- function(i) {
  y<-unlist(df$a[i]);
  z<-y[y==df$b[i]];
  ifelse(length(z)==0, y[1], z)
}
# iterate through each row and apply the function    
df$c <- sapply(1:nrow(df),  func)
```

Comment: why is that , users don't show the courtesy to give reasons to downvote!!

Comment: @Zideg does it answer your question?